# Kendo UI Editor - Force all new links to new window

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

We are using the Kendo UI Editor control. How can I force it to only insert links that will open into a new window (i.e. target="_blank")?

This needs to be done in javascript, not Razor. I have tried getting it on the execute and select events, but neither have worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Automatically check the "Open link in new window" checkbox in the "Insert link" dialog. Here is a sample implementation: http://jsbin.com/ekibud/1/edit. The idea is to subscribe to the `execute` event of the editor and if the command is "createlink" check the checkbox. Here is the required code:

   ```
   $("#editor").kendoEditor({
      execute: function(e) {
         if (e.name == "createlink") {
           setTimeout(function() {
             $("#k-editor-link-target").attr("checked", true);
           });
         }
      }
   });
   ```
2. Find all links in the editor content and set their target attribute. This can be done via JavaScript and a regular expression replace:

   ```
   var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");

   var html = editor.value();

   // remove all existing target attributes

   html = html.replace(/<a[^>]*/, function(a) {
     // first remove existing target attribute
     a = a.replace(/target\s*=\s*['"][^"']*['"]/, '');

     // then add a target attribute
     a += ' target="_blank"';

     return a;
   });
   // Use the updated html
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Our first solution was to add a target attribute to all a-tags, like your second answer. I attached it to the 'change' event of the editor and used jQuery's $.each to loop through all a-tags. The final solution was to write a custom tool for the toolbar that would hide the checkbox for open in a new window and force all links upon save.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution without assigning editor value every time

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");

$(editor.body).find("a").attr("target", "_blank");
```